# Android + Volley + Connector PHP Não insere dados no banco SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, android-studio, web-service, volley

Estou tentando inserir dados provenientes de uma aplicação Android no banco de dados SQL Server, e estou utilizando Volley e connector PHP. A conexão está ok, e as buscas aparecem normalmente na tela do dispositivo. Estou precisando inserir dados, mas todos os testes foram sem sucesso. Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Código ***cadastro.php***:

```
$username = "";   
$email = "";    
$password = ""; 
if(isset($_POST['nome'])){    
    $username = $_POST['nome'];   
}
if(isset($_POST['email'])){    
    $email = $_POST['email'];    
}
if(isset($_POST['senha'])){    
    $password = $_POST['senha'];    
}
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email)){
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Usuario (nome, email, senha) VALUES ('".$_POST['nome']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['senha']."')";
}
include_once "busca.php";
?>
```

Código ***cadastro.java***, do Android Studio, onde faço a conexão com Volley:

```
public class Cadastro extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText txtNome, txtEmail, txtSenha, txtRepeteSenha;
    Button btnCadastrar;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;


    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);
        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        txtNome = findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtEmail = findViewById(R.id.mail);
        txtSenha = findViewById(R.id.key);
        txtRepeteSenha = findViewById(R.id.key_again);
        btnCadastrar = findViewById(R.id.cadastrar);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        btnCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String nome, email, senha;
                nome = txtNome.getText().toString();
                email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
                senha = txtSenha.getText().toString();
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Cadastro.this);

                String url = "http://192.168.15.17/cadastro.php";
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cadastro.this);
                                //alertDialog.setTitle("Resposta do servidor:");
                                alertDialog.setMessage("Resposta: " + response);
                                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        txtNome.setText("");
                                        txtEmail.setText("");
                                        txtSenha.setText("");
                                    }
                                });
                                AlertDialog alertDialog2 = alertDialog.create();
                                alertDialog2.show();
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(Cadastro.this, "Erro!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                error.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("nome", nome);
                        params.put("email", email);
                        params.put("senha", senha);
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                queue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        });
    }
```

***conexao.php***

```
<?php

    $serverName = "DESKTOP-AOQ0PBR\TESTE"; 
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"appscout");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não consegue inserir pois você apenas criou uma string concatenada com valores postados.

Criei uma solução com o código comentado:

```
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email)){
     $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Usuario (nome, email, senha) VALUES (?,?,?)"; // String que contém o comando de inserção
        try {
            // preparação
          $st = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql1, [$nome, $email, $senha]);
          sqlsrv_execute($st); // <-- inserção das variáveis nos seus respectivos campos

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            // se algo der errado no meio do caminho mostre a mensagem de erro
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```

Comment: Oi Andrei. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, todavia eu consigo conectar com o banco utilizando o **conexao.php** no include. O **busca.php** no final do código traz os resultados solicitados do banco. O que não consigo mesmo é inserir.

Comment: @PauloLara coloque o código da conexao com o banco na pergunta.

Comment: Andrei, deu certo aqui com o teu código. Eu estava pecando no detalhe do post, e com aqueles "?" dentro dos VALUES. Vou seguir em frente para a próxima batalha. Muito obrigado. Resolvido.

Comment: ok... vou só editar a resposta pois você inseriu novas informações na pergunta.

Comment: ok. Com essas suas respostas já encontrei o rumo no delete e update.

Comment: @PauloLara tranquilo!